# When I store files in HDFS, will they be replicated?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am new to Hadoop.

When I store Excel files using `hadoop -fs put` commoad, it is stored in HDFS.

Replication factor is 3.

**My question is:** Does it take 3 copies and store them into 3 nodes each?

Answer (score 10):

Here is a comic for HDFS working.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-zw6KHOtbT4MmRkZWJjYzEtYjI3Ni00NTFjLWE0OGItYTU5OGMxYjc0N2M1/edit?pli=1

Comment: question: Is there a risk of data loss if the following happens (Imagine a busy network and i/o): datanode1 writes block successfully and sends an ack back to the client. datanode1 dies before being able to fully complete the replication to another datanode. datanode1 never comes back. ?

Comment: @Gevorg I believe in that case, the computation would have to be re-run, as the data would not exist since it never reached the required replication factor.

Answer (score 2):

**Does it take 3 copies and store them into 3 nodes each**.

> answer is: **NO**

[image]

*Replication is done in **pipelining***
that is it copies some part of file to datanode1 and then copies to datanode2 from datanode1 and to datanode3 from datanode1

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html#Replication+Pipelining

see here for Replication Pipelining

Comment: question: Is there a risk of data loss if the following happens (Imagine a busy network and i/o): datanode1 writes block successfully and sends an ack back to the client. datanode1 dies before being able to fully complete the replication to another datanode. datanode1 never comes back. ?

Answer (score 1):

Your HDFS Client (hadoop fs in this case) will be given the block names and datanode locations (the first being the closest location if the NameNode can determine this from the rack awareness script) of where to store these files by the NameNode.

The client then copies the blocks to the closest Data node. The data node is then responsible for copying the block to a second datanode (preferably on another rack), where finally the second will copy to the third (on the same rack as the third).

So your client will only copy data to one of the data nodes, and the framework will take care of the replication between datanodes.

Answer (score 0):

It will store the original file to one (or more in case of large files) blocks. These blocks will be  replicated to two other nodes.

Edit: My answer applies to Hadoop 2.2.0. I have no experience with prior versions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will be replicated in 3 nodes (maximum upto 3 nodes).

The Hadoop Client is going to break the data file into smaller “Blocks”, and place those blocks on different machines throughout the cluster.  The more blocks you have, the more machines that will be able to work on this data in parallel.  At the same time, these machines may be prone to failure, so it is safe to insure that every block of data is on multiple machines at once to avoid data loss.

So each block will be replicated in the cluster as its loaded.  The standard setting for Hadoop is to have (3) copies of each block in the cluster.  This can be configured with the dfs.replication parameter in the file hdfs-site.xml.

And replicating data is not a drawback of Hadoop at all, in fact it is an integral part of what makes Hadoop effective. Not only does it provide you with a good degree of fault tolerance, but it also helps in running your map tasks close to the data to avoid putting extra load on the network (read about data locality).

Comment: Just to clarify: Default block size is 64MB so one block per file should be enough in the OP's case as he wants to store Excel files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it make n(replications factor) number copies in hdfs

use this command to find out the location of file, find #rack it is stored, what is the block name on all racks

hadoop fsck /path/to/your/directory -files -blocks -locations -racks

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to load data into hdfs with replication

`hadoop fs -Ddfs.replication=1 -put big.file /tmp/test1.file` 
and `-Ddfs.replication=1` you can define number of replication copy will created while to loading data into hdfs