# a file on hdfs with 3 replication will store on 3 hosts?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, replication

[image]

a file on hdfs with 3 replication will store on 3 hosts ?
Or store on not only 3 hosts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file with replication factor 3 will have each of its blocks that alltogether constitute it, stored three times (HDFS stores blocks, not files). If you have 3 nodes (as in the top part of your figure), then each block will be stored once in each node. If you have 1 node, all blocks will be stored in the same node (once, as brandon.bell commented). If you have 5 nodes and each file uses more than one blocks (as in the bottom of your figure), then, yes, more than 3 nodes will be used.

The reason is fault tolerance. Assuming that any two hosts become unreachable (in the bottom figure), you can still retrieve all the blocks that compose your files. For example, if host4 and host5 fail, then you can still retrieve block1 from host1 and block2 from host2.

For more details, please refer to [this documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html#Data+Replication). I also found a nice comic about hadoop replication, in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20238244/2516301).

Comment: This is right except if you only have one node, the block will not be stored three times on that host (unless you're running multiple datanode instances).

Comment: if i have more than 5 nodes, i want it store on 3 nodes. Then i will read the file fast on these 3 nodes（because not need get blocks from other node）. But how to store file on 3 nodes ?

Comment: If you have 5 nodes and you replication factor is set at 3, the Namenode will handle the distribution of the files to three of the nodes.